# Query tables from multiple servers with postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I have several databases on the different PostgreSQL servers with the tables with the same columns in it
(installs_1, installs_2 and installs_3)
`installs(country varchar, date datetime,paid boolean, installs int)`

 I want to write a function that a user could use to query across all these databases at once, how can I do it?
my query is:`select country,count(*) from t1,t2`

Comment: Have you considered using a foreign data wrapper?

Comment: See here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189654

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PostgreSQL extension that offer this feature is the [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html). Here is an example of how to set it up:

First you create the extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw
```

After that you create a server pointing to the foreign postgres server

```
CREATE SERVER remote_postgres 
 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
 OPTIONS (dbname 'mydb', host 'remoteserver', port '5432');
```

Then an user mapping, so that an user in your current database may access the foreign database:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR local_user
SERVER remote_postgres
OPTIONS (user 'foreign_user', password 'secret');
```

And finally you create a foreign table to link both tables

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_table_test
(id INT, description TEXT)
SERVER remote_postgres
OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'table_test');
```

Once your table is created you can query it like you'd query a normal/local table:

```
SELECT * FROM foreign_table_test
```

Further reading:

- A [`closer look`](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/21/foreign-data-wrappers-postgresql-postgres_fdw/) into postgres_fdw
- postgres_fdw [`documentation examples`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html#id-1.11.7.42.16)

Comment: This answers how to connect to remote databases but I don't fully understand how would you query multiple databases at once.

Comment: This seems to answer my comment: https://dev.to/aurelmegn/setting-up-distributed-database-architecture-with-postgresql-261